# AngularJS Metadata with dynamic async content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, metadata

I have an angular application running within a .net application and I am trying to implement meta tags for SEO and other purposes. The problem I'm having is that I don't know the page title etc until after a call to an external site.

For example, a URL I might navigate to is `www.mywebsite.com/people/1234`.
This would make a call to `www.apiwebsite.com/api/person/get?id=1234` which will then return information such as name to be used in the title of the page and other important metadata.

The problem here is while this works from a users perspective, crawlers and open grid won't wait for that information and so only the websites default metadata is visible.

I have looked at server side rendering for angularjs (angular 1) as an option but was unable to find anything usable, is anyone familiar with something I can use to ensure the correct data for the page is provided to search engines etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your application and requirements there are a few ways of doing this.

1. You can use a service such as [prerender.io](https://prerender.io)
2. You can setup [rendertron](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron) or [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) to prerender your pages
3. In case you upgrade to Angular 6+, you can use [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

I have used puppeteer as a build step, when most of the important information wasn't too dynamic and that worked really well. A bunch of people seem to be pretty happy with Rendertron and prerender.io, too.